# How to prove that expansivity is a topological property in a compact space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

A homeomorphism $f:X\rightarrow X$ is called *expansive* if there exists a constant $\delta>0$ such that if $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))<\delta$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $x=y$.

How to prove that if $X$ is compact, this property is topological, i.e. depends not on the metric $d$, but on the topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $d$ and $d^\prime$ are metrics that both induce the topology $\tau$ on the compact space $(X,\tau)$. Suppose further that $f : X \to X$ is expansive with regard to $d$ with expansivity constant $\delta > 0$. $X$ is compact, so we can cover it with a finite amount of open balls of radius $\delta / 2$ in the metric $d$. We will denote this open cover of X by $$\mathcal{U} = \lbrace B_d^{i}(x_i, \delta /2) \mid 1 \leq i \leq n \rbrace.  $$ $X$ is compact and $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, so by the Lebesgue number lemma there is a $\delta^{\prime} > 0$ such that every subset of $X$ having diameter less than $\delta^{\prime}$ in the metric $d^{\prime}$ is contained in one of these balls.

Thus if $d^{\prime}(x,y) < \delta^{\prime}$, we have that $x,y \in B_d^{i}(x_i, \delta /2) \textrm{ for some } 1 \leq i \leq n $, from which it follows by the triangle inequality that $$d(x,y) \leq d(x, x_i) + d(x_i, y) < \delta / 2 + \delta / 2 = \delta $$

Hence if we have $d^{\prime}(f^{n}(x), f^{n}(y)) < \delta^{\prime}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we also have $d(f^{n}(x), f^{n}(y)) < \delta$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $x = y$ by the assumption. Therefore $f$ is expansive also with regard to $d^{\prime}$, with expansivity constant $\delta^{\prime}$.

This shows that the expansivity of $f$ does not depend on the particular choice of metric.

Comment: I have no objection to using the Lebegue lemma.I'd like to show how to get $\delta'$ without it: $\exists \delta'>0\; (\forall x,y\in X\; d(x,y)\geq \delta \implies d'(x,y)\geq \delta').$ If not, let $d(x_n,y_n)\geq \delta$  and $d'(x_n,y_n)<1/n.$ Then there is a  subsequence $(k_n)_{n\in N}$ of $N$ such that  $(x_{k_n})_{n\in N}$ and $(y_{k_n})_{n\in N}$ are $d'$-Cauchy  sequences, both converging to some $x\in X.$  But then $ id_X$ is not continuous from $(X, d')$ to $(X,d)$ so the metrics are not equivalent....+1 for your A.

Comment: Nice, that is indeed probably a quicker way of proving the assertion.

Comment: Thank you. Follow-up : Prove that equivalent metrics $d, d'$ for a compact metrizable space  $X$ are uniformly equivalent :$\exists k,k'>0 \; \forall  x,y \in X  \; (k  d(x,y) \leq  d'(x,y) \leq  k'  d(x,y) ) \;).$

Comment: I apologize for my previous comment: For $X=[0,1]$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d'(x,y)=|x-y|+|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|,$ the metrics $ d,d'$ are equivalent but not uniformly equivalent.